# Problem with Quartz and Tasks Simultaneous

Tags: spring, task, quartz-scheduler, jobs, quartz

I have some problems with a project that includes Spring Framework and Quartz tasks. I have some tasks that starts each one minute and a have a loop with 3 companies (object Company) inside this loop.

Each company must starts one particular task simultaneously, but generally, these 3 taks have duration longer than one minute.

Then a need these 3 tasks continue executing simultaneously (3 threads at the same time), but each one must wait their similar tasks (new tasks after one minute) finish and then it starts again.

I'm using Spring and I'm using taskExecutor to start de new thread. I dont know if its the best way to call the job class.

I hope I was clear.